# manipulate image in codeigniter after upload

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a successful upload script and it returns the path (later inserted to DB table). Now I realize that since my site should allow large photo (not in size but dimensions), I should try and resize the photos (in MBs). I came across image manipulation in CI. How can I resize picture with given path and delete original picture (not sure if it is done automatically)? Code below shows the last bit of my upload function:

```
  /*Image Manipulation Class*/
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $fullImagePath;
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
            $this->image_lib->resize();


        return $fullImagePath;
```

Comment: "resize the photos (in MBs)". Do you mean that you want to reduce the filesize, but not the dimensions?

Comment: Yes...is that possible?

Comment: You can use image_lib->resize() to reduce the quality of the image, but the quality value is a 1-100 setting and doesn't let you specify MB. What is the issue with the size? Saving space? Reducing page load time?

Comment: not having a problem right now because the site not yet active...but I fear once it is so it becomes a problem. What you think?

Comment: Well if page load becomes a problem, I think the best practice is to create smaller, low quality thumbnails on upload that would be used on pages that don't need the full size picture loaded. If it becomes a space issue, you might want to set a maximum filesize limit for the uploads (or get more disk space).

Comment: I have unlimited storage with my host. So that's not the problem. But maybe I could launch now and consider later the option of various pages loading various sizes